# How to save changes in a CSV file using Mac Numbers?

Tags: macos, numbers, csv

I have a .CSV file, it opens well in Numbers ~4, but when i do changes in that file (editing row color, etc) i can't correctly save it. If i try to save it as .numbers - when i open that .numbers file, it gives me blank rows, everything is empty.

Comment: CSV files don't store row color or other formatting details. You will need to save the CSV file in another format like Numbers of export it to XLSX.

Answer (score 3):

Try to keep it as a .csv file.

While you have numbers open go to the menu bar and click on file > Export to > CSV...

Comment: It produces the same CSV file without my changes :D

Comment: CSV only contains data, not formatting. Please share a sample numbers file or screenshot that shows your issue.

Comment: Exporting a CSV with Numbers doesn't edit the original file. It only allows you to overwrite it. It doesn't open a CSV as much as import it into a .numbers file.

Answer (score -2):

It seems like Numbers can't edit .csv files.

You can use this tool:

[Free .CSV text file editor for Mac OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15946/free-csv-text-file-editor-for-mac-os-x)

Comment: Numbers can open and export csv. I do this all the time on Mac and iPad version. Could you elaborate on that seems statement?