# Running Microsoft Office 2004 on a MacBook Air 2017

Tags: macbook-pro

High Sierra 10.13.4, I have Microsoft Office:Mac Student and Teacher edition, but when I try to install it says PowerPc not supported? Can I get around this issue. Thanks, Rose

Comment: Get yourself a current version of Microsoft Office or use LIbreOffice! Don't waste you time with SheepShaver as suggested in the answer by jmh! -- Microsoft Office 2004 Student & Teacher Edition for Mac is a version of Microsoft Office developed for Mac OS X. The software was originally written for PowerPC Macs, so Macs with Intel CPUs must run the program under Mac OS X's Rosetta emulation layer. For this reason, it is not compatible with Mac OS X 10.7 and newer.

Comment: @Rose, The 2nd part of my answer is apparently not very popular so I apologize for mentioning it.  In addition to LibreOffice, there is also OpenOffice which runs fine on HighSierra.  I thought you were stuck with Microsoft Office, hence my answer.   If you are just looking for an office suite, Macs come with one.  A collection of office apps. It is known by the specific package name. It includes Pages, a word processing app, a spreadsheet program called Numbers, and a presentation package called Keynote.  All three are on your computer unless you removed them for some reason.

Comment: Rose, the easiest thing to do is get a free [Outlook.com](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/247008/119271) account which entitles you to online versions of Word, Excel, etc.  All of the docs you have will automatically be converted to the new modern Office formats at no charge and you don’t have to worry about installing a thing.

Comment: Thanks Allan, but the online versions of Word, Excel, etc are not free w Outlook. The first month is free only.

Answer (score 1):

**Can I get round this issue?**

Not easily. This is 16-year-old software, and lots has changed since then, so that a modern OS can't run it.

While it is possible to 'emulate' an older computing environment that could run the software, this is complicated.

Furthermore, Word 2004 can't open most modern .docx files, which were introduced in 2007. So it wouldn't be very useful to you anyway.

Software has a time to live, and a time to die. Either buy a new version of Office, compatible with your OS, or use a free Office 'clone' like LibreOffice. You can read and save Word files from Apple's Pages, too.

Answer (score -2):

You apparently have a very old version of Microsoft Office. You need to upgrade to a more recent version. There is an emulation program called [SheepShaver](https://www.emaculation.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=7360&sid=4c3196dbfdc414e2aa2f84278344279a) that will do just what you want. The installation directions are given [here.](https://emaculation.com/doku.php/sheepshaver_mac_os_x_setup) And the home page for [Sheepshaver](https://sheepshaver.cebix.net) describes what the emulator does. An emulator, in this case, is a software package that will act like a PowerPC system so you can run PowerPC codes. Once you have Sheepshaver running you should be able to load and run your Microsoft ( i hate writing that - lol) software.

Comment: Other than the the first and second sentences of this answer about MS Office being obsolete and a newer version being required, everything else should be completely avoided.  Getting an emulator to run a 16 year old piece of software for a completely different architecture is introducing problems a computer non-expert won't know how to deal with.  Also, is there some moral issue with Microsoft that elicits hate when you write about loading their software?

Comment: @Allan Well, I had read about emulators so I felt obligated to mention them. If you know more about them then you should probably write an answer telling the OP your concerns. I've never used an emulator so I am not familiar with the problems you mentioned but would like to know more.  Your answer would be appreciated by me and probably others.  Since I first recommended that she upgrade her Microsoft package I don't see a reason to delete my answer unless I learn more about my other option. Thank you for pointing it out though. And yes I've hated Microsoft for many years.

Comment: An answer about emulators is irrelevant here which is why I said “avoided” and regardless of what we know or don’t know about them, it’s another layer of complexity that a user who couldn’t distinguish between architectures would now have to deal with.  It’s your call, but something  this complex shouldn’t be recommended if you have no experience.  As for hating Microsoft, keep in mind, there would be no Apple without them